# FormControlLabel vs. InputLabel in Material UI

Tags: material-ui

What is the difference (in purpose and/or behavior) between a `FormControlLabel` and an `InputLabel` in Material-UI (React) version 4+?

Answer (score 2):

See [Comparison](https://smartdevpreneur.com/mui-labels-textfield-labels-input-labels-and-form-labels/):

> - An InputLabel is a specific kind of FormLabel. It has class    MuiInputLabel-root and MuiFormLabel-root applied in the DOM
> - A FormLabel only has class MuiInputLabel-root applied and so is not an    InputLabel
> - An InputLabel component is both a standalone component and    is a compositional component inside a TextField.